# NSTimer Thrashing - Do I Need to Handle It?

Tags: ios, nstimer

It's possible this question is already out there, but I couldn't find it. My question is essentially this. If I have a repeating NSTimer that executes something that takes longer than the timer interval, will there be some thrashing that will crash the app? Alternatively, does the new time event not start until the task being executed completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the NSTimer runs on the run loop it was created in, I think it can't ever re-enter the method it calls. This [document on the run loops](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) confirms this (see the "Timer Sources" section:

> "Similarly, if a timer fires when the run loop is in the middle of
>   executing a handler routine, the timer waits until the next time
>   through the run loop to invoke its handler routine"

Answer (score 1):

You can always just schedule an nstimer that only occurs once and then reschedule it when the function completes.

```
- (void)myFunction {
    ......stuff that your method does
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(myFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was one of understanding repeating timers, not of finding alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

A repeating timer always schedules itself based on the scheduled firing time, as opposed to the actual firing time. For example, if a timer is scheduled to fire at a particular time and every 5 seconds after that, the scheduled firing time will always fall on the original 5 second time intervals, even if the actual firing time gets delayed. If the firing time is delayed so far that it passes one or more of the scheduled firing times, the timer is fired only once for that time period; the timer is then rescheduled, after firing, for the next scheduled firing time in the future.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as you avoid kicking off some asynchronous jobs, you'll be fine. If asynchronously dispatching tasks that routinely take longer than the interval between invocations of the timer, then that queue can get backed up. If doing animations, the timer will fire even though the animation may not be done.

---

Let me provide two examples. For both examples, let's imagine that we create a timer that fires once per second:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(handleTimer:)
                                            userInfo:@"tick"
                                             repeats:YES];
```

**First example:** Let's assume we have some serial queue:

```
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

Furthermore, let's assume we have a `NSTimer` handler that does something like:

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, timer.userInfo);

    [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSLog(@"%s starting some slow process; has %d operations queued", __FUNCTION__, self.queue.operationCount);

        // to simulate a slow process, let's just sleep for 10 seconds

        sleep(10);

        NSLog(@"%s done", __FUNCTION__);
    }];
}
```

Because the timer is firing every second, and because the timer handler returns almost immediately (because all it's doing is queueing up background operations), by the time the first queued operation (which takes 10 seconds) finishes and the second one starts, there are already 10 operations sitting on that background queue. And by the time the second background operation finishes, when the third operation kicks off, there are 19 operations queued up. It only gets worse because the `NSTimer` handler will simply keep getting called, firing more quickly than the slower background operations are getting cleared out of their queue. Obviously, if the handler did everything synchronously in the current queue, though, everything is fine, and there's no backlogging, no "thrashing" by the `NSTimer`.

**Second example:** Another example of this problem is animation. Let's assume that the timer handler method is doing something like the following, that starts a 10 second animation that moves a `UIImageView`:

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, timer.userInfo);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.imageView.frame = [self determineNewFrame];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

This won't work (or more accurately, you'll see the subsequent invocations of the timer call `handleTimer` even though the previous animation is not done). If you're going to do this, you have to keep track of whether the animation is done. You have to do something like:

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, timer.userInfo);

    if (!self.animating)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s initiating another animation", __FUNCTION__);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                         animations:^{
                             self.animating = YES;
                             self.imageView.frame = [self determineNewFrame];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.animating = NO;
                         }];
    }
}
```

You either have to do some state flag (like my boolean `animation` flag) to prevent additional animations before the first one is done, or just not use recurring timers and simply kick off another timer in the `completion` block of the `UIView` animation class method.

Comment: The task I had in mind is moving views around with animation using blocks. I was worried that these move requests would get in a log jam. I suppose I could test it out simply enough by piling on way more requests than I need and invalidate the timer with a gesture or something and watch what happens.

Comment: Yes, that may well be a problem (because when you initiate an animation, the call will generally return immediately and animation takes place later). Yeah, I'd be inclined to `invalidate`, but at that point, why bother with recurring timers at all.

Comment: When I test this, instantiating a large number of views to stress test the app, what looks like is happening is that the animation of the view movements turns choppy. But it runs for hours without there seeming to be a problem. I currently have the views moving around in circles. It seems like if this were actually a problem, the views would start jumping around randomly, but they aren't.

Comment: @VictorEngel if it's working for you, that's great. I've expanded my answer with examples of repeating `NSTimer`-related problems, not only of the problematic background operation, which I originally contemplated in my answer, but also problematic animation, too. I gather that you must be doing animation in a different manner (e.g. maybe you're not using the built in animation, but moving stuff yourself, I don't know) if you're not experiencing this problem. But the proof is in the pudding: If it works for you as it is, that's brilliant.

Comment: thanks for expanding on your answer. After reflecting on my code, I think I've figured out why it is not turning out to be a problem for me. The only thing I'm doing in thread blocks is view movement with animation, and the timing is set to be coordinated with the timer. Everything else is done in the run loop, so what BlackRider says applies.